# Is Javascript supported by `flyspell-prog-mode`?

Tags: javascript, flyspell

Which programming languages are supported by `flyspell-prog-mode`? Is Javascript?

I can get `flyspell-prog-mode` to spellcheck comments on Python buffers, but it doesn't seem to work on Javascript buffers.

Comment: Seems to work fine here (emacs 29.0.50).  What happens if you start with `emacs -Q`? If that works, then your init file is the culprit. Please add that info as well as your emacs version to the question.

Comment: It _does_ work with `emacs -Q`- I will check my init file. Thanks @NickD

Answer (score 1):

With `trees-itter`, I found that the variable `flyspell-prog-text-faces` isn't being set correctly. I needed to add the following block to my `init.el`:

```
(after! flyspell
  (add-hook! prog-mode
    (setq! flyspell-prog-text-faces
           '(font-lock-string-face
             font-lock-comment-face
             font-lock-doc-face
             tree-sitter-hl-face:string
             tree-sitter-hl-face:comment
             tree-sitter-hl-face:doc))))
```

You can use `M-x list-faces-display` to see which other faces you might want to add to the list. Before the chage, it was only set to `(font-lock-string-face font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face)`. I adapted the fix from this [doom emacs discourse thread](https://discourse.doomemacs.org/t/spell-fu-is-not-working-as-expected-in-most-programming-comments/4255/2).